# 6 text boxes, used click to find them, but sendKeys() is sending all text to the last text box

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

**Following is the code i wrote for the text fields.**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("Sathiya");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys("Rengarajan");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("sathiyarengarjan@setmore.com");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[3]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[3]")).sendKeys("3295739258");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[4]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[4]")).sendKeys("Ascendas");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[5]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[3]/android.widget.EditText[5]")).sendKeys("Taramani");
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**First 5 clicks finds the exact text box, but when sendkeys is executed for the first 5 text boxes- all the values are getting entered into the 6th text box. When click is executed for the 6 text box, i am getting error stating unable to locate element. Any suggestions?**

Server Logs:

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 60.46 seconds

Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:30'

System info: host: 'SR6-SM-MACAIR.local', ip: '10.5.3.239', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.7.0_21'

Session ID: 4d7c958f-9d8f-4989-8960-e2999cf83f75

Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver

Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, app=/usr/local/android-sdk/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/SETMORE-ANDROIDAPP/Setmore.apk, javascriptEnabled=true, appActivity=com.adaptavant.setmore.ui.StartActivity, browserName=, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={platformVersion=4.4, app=/usr/local/android-sdk/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/SETMORE-ANDROIDAPP/Setmore.apk, deviceName=Google Nexus 4, platformName=Android, browserName=, appActivity=com.adaptavant.setmore.ui.StartActivity, appPackage=com.adaptavant.setmore}, locationContextEnabled=false, appPackage=com.adaptavant.setmore, platformVersion=4.4, databaseEnabled=false, platformName=Android, deviceName=Google Nexus 4, webStorageEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]

Comment: I don't understand what `.manage()` and `.navigate().back()` are doing. If you paste Appium server logs I can provide better help.

Comment: Please paste the server logs. When the "unknown server error ocurred" happens, it's usually because of what happened right before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need `back` after each `sendkeys`.
Some problems in your code --

1. Also your Xpath is prone to errors if minor layout changes take place on the page.
2. You dont send implicit waits continuously in code.

Assuming all the textboxes are on same page in the visible area... you can do following --

a. Search for all editText(textboxes) like this--

```
elements = driver.get_webelements("//android.widget.EditText")
```

b) Send text to each textbox

```
for element in elements:
    element.sendKeys("Hello world!");
```

If there more textboxes in same view but need scrolling, you will have to add scrolling logic there.

**Note:** code above is in python but I guess it should not be difficult for you to convert it over to Java